# How to add a delay between two TCP Sampler requests in a single thread group?

Tags: jmeter

To achieve:- Send multiple strings as TCP requests to a server with each string consisting of variable time i.e. each string sent should have the variable current date and time.

Sample String to be sent:- $Header,iTriangle1,UX101_0206_STD_WIFI_4.11.93,NR,90,H,12354,KA01G1234,0,26082022,**${date}**,0.000000,,0.000000,,0.0,0.0,0,0.0,0.00,0.00,,0,1,26.1,4.2,0,C,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,000000,010,613055,0.000,0.000,0,()*42

**${date}** has been set in User Defined Variables as  `${__groovy(new Date().format("HHmmss"\, TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')),)}`

Answer (score 1):

1. Either put a [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) sampler between them:

   [image]
2. Or put a [Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) of your choice, i.e. a [Constant Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Timer) as a child of the Sampler 2

   [image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. For me, both the ways suggested are not working. I want to send a single string multiple times i.e. each string should have a distinct time.

Comment: Your question was about setting the delay. If you want to send new timestamp each time - put the [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) directly into TCP Samplers body as [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) are evaluated only once when the test starts hence your `${date}` variable will have the same value until you restart the test.